# How do I generate a unique ID from web/javascript and then generate same unique ID in android App?

Tags: javascript, android, uuid

Hi I would like to generate a unique ID from web/Javascript and also be able to generate the same unique ID in app without the two communicating. I will not be using PhoneGap just pure javascript or probably a light library.

I was initially planning to use the device ID but its not accessible from `JavaScipt` without using PhoneGap. There are many ways I know how to generate a unique ID from `native Android app` but I'd like to be able to generate the same one from the `Web/JavaScipt`.

Any help is appreciated thanks so much.

Comment: You can generate unique number using Date() like var now = new Date().getTime(); which will return always an unique number. But same number from other place it looks like impossible.

Comment: It won't be unique if two systems can generate the same value

Comment: thanks for the answers. it was good to get a reality check.

Answer (score 2):

***Unique ID*** Suppose to  be Generated Only Once.

Now come to your question:

> How do I generate a unique ID from web/javascript and then generate
>   same unique ID in android App?

You **can not generate the same ID** from two different places i.e. from Android Native and JavaScript/Web. Please keep in mind, **not possible**.

**Note : If you are able to generate the same ID again then that ID is not unique at all.**